# AppDomains Not Working for Office (Word) Add-in in preventing domains from opening in new window on Mac

Tags: ms-word, office365, office-js, add-in, office-addins

I have something like the following in my Word Add-in

```
<AppDomains>
    <AppDomain>https://google.com</AppDomain>
</AppDomains>
```

When navigating to `google.com` in my Word add-on on Mac it always opens in a new window.
In the browser it opens in the taskpane. Is this a bug, or am I doing something wrong?
AppDomains seems to work fine for Outlook Add-ons, as well as when I side-load the add-on on office.com

[1] https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/office/dev/add-ins/reference/manifest/appdomain

Answer (score 0):

Typing the full domain should work  (i.e. add https://www.google.com to AppDomains)  also I  am assuming you are navigating using windows.location.href = "https://www.google.com"

Comment: Hi Juan, Thanks for the input. The documentation states that www is a separate subdomain and is treated separately. There is no mention that a subdomain is required.

Anyways, even with the www specified, I am seeing the open in new tab issue on `window.location.href` calls.

Comment: Thanks James, you are right on the subdomain piece and the team is investigating, but if i add the full domain and the use the same in href i got it working. can you please share in what Word builds are you observing this? thanks!

Comment: Hi Juan, appreciate you looking into this for me. I'm on Word for Mac, Version 16.44 (20121301). The corresponding version of Outlook is handling the AppDomain correctly.